# What are the generic code-signing identities for iOS and OSX?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, code-signing

unless you override the XCode defaults, it will use generic identitifiers to search your keychain for a matching code-signing identity.

what are the generic identifiers for iOS and OSX?

Answer (score 2):

they are:

*iOS*

- `iPhone Developer`
- `iPhone Distribution`

*OSX*

- `Mac Developer`
- `Mac Distribution`

> ***Note:*** the reason these work is that under the hood, XCode is using the `codesign` command line tool, which searches against the *Common Name* field of all certificates in the keychain(s) when it tries to find a match for a given identity value (ee the *SIGNING IDENTITIES* section of the [codesign man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html) for more details). 
>
> When you create a certificate in the Apple Developer portal, they prefix your common name with one of these generic identifiers. For example, the common name of an iPhone developer certificate for J. Random Developer might be `iPhone Developer: J. Random Developer (ABC0123XYZ)`
>
> You can inspect the common names of your certificates via the *Keychain Access* app: launch Keychain Access (under *Applications/Utilities*), select the *My Certificates* category, select a certificate, and choose *Get Info* from the *File* menu (**⌘I**).